# "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" Error using pyvirtualdisplay in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyvirtualdisplay

I'm getting the following error when i try to run this simple python code

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
disp = Display()
disp.start()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\disp.py", line 4, in <module>
    disp = Display()
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\display.py", line 54, in __init__
    self._obj = cls(
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\xvfb.py", line 44, in __init__
    AbstractDisplay.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\abstractdisplay.py", line 85, in __init__
    helptext = get_helptext(program)
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\util.py", line 13, in get_helptext
    p = subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Had this error - the dev says there's no windows support: https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay/issues/73